# update data base on conditions

Tags: php, laravel

I've made my update form to get data in 2 conditions

1. when user set **new quantity** of product
2. when user apply **coupon code**

They should work side-by-side whiteout interrupting each other, the **LOGIC** is:

1. If user changed `quantity` update it
2. if user add `coupon`, apply it
3. if user changed `quantity and add coupon`, update both.

## issue

1. my code `works` if i change quantity.
2. my code `doesn't work` on coupon update.
3. my code `doesn't work` with both input together.
4. i get `2 sessions alert` on changing quantity.

> PS: My issues are refer to my `if` statements. (basically i need help to fix my `if's`)

## Codes

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

  //list of coupons
  $coupons = Coupon::all();
  //get current time
  $mytime = Carbon::now();

  $qty = $request->input('quantity');
  $productId = $request->proId;
  $products = Product::where('id', $productId)->firstOrFail();
  $stock = $products->stock;


  //coupons
    $couponcode = $request->input('coupon');
    $catId = Coupon::where('category_id', $products->category_id)
                    ->where('value_to', '>=', $mytime)
                    ->when($couponcode, function ($query) use ($couponcode) {
                      return $query->where('title', $couponcode);
                    })
                    ->first();
    if($catId == $couponcode){ //first if
      $coupon = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
        'name' => $catId->title,
        'type' => 'coupon',
        'target' => 'item',
        'value' => -$catId->amount,
      ));
    }else{
      Session::flash('danger', 'Your request cannot be handle, please try again!');
    }
  //end coupons

  if($qty<$stock && empty($couponcode)){ //second if

    Cart::update($id, array(
      'quantity' => array(
          'relative' => false,
          'value' => $request->input('quantity'),
      ),
    ));
    Session::flash('success', 'Cart is updated.');
    return redirect()->route('cart.index');

  }elseif(!empty($couponcode) && $catId == $couponcode){ //third if
    Cart::update($id, array(
      'conditions' => $coupon,
    ));
    Session::flash('success', 'Coupon applied successfully.');
    return redirect()->route('cart.index');
  }else{ // fourth if
    Session::flash('danger', 'Your request cannot be handle, please try again!');
    return redirect()->route('cart.index');
  }
}
```

## Screenshot

[image: screen1]

Anyone can help with that?

Answer (score 0):

When you create  `$catId` you are getting an eloquent model because you use `first()`.

$catId = Coupon::where('category_id', $products->category_id)
                    ->where('value_to', '>=', $mytime)
                    ->when($couponcode, function ($query) use ($couponcode) {
                      return $query->where('title', $couponcode);
                    })
                    ->first();

Then you compare it:

```
 if($catId == $couponcode)
```

Which will never be true

Solution is to get the value you need from the query correctly:

```
...->first()->column_name;
```

Comment: i still get error on adding coupon and see 2 alert on changing quantity. `->first()->category_id;`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the column name of the **couponcode** (`$catId->title` or `$catId->category_id` or whatever it is) in your condition**s**:

```
if($catId->title == $couponcode){ //first if
  $coupon = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
    'name' => $catId->title,
    'type' => 'coupon',
    'target' => 'item',
    'value' => $catId->amount,
  ));
}else{
  Session::flash('danger', 'Your request cannot be handle, please try again!');
}
```

Similarly at:

```
elseif(!empty($couponcode) && $catId->title == $couponcode){ //third if
```

---

**UPDATE**
You should rearrange your if blocks as:
**1.** If both (quantity & code) are given
  **nested >** if quantity is lesser than stock and code is correct `update the cart`
**2.** If just quantity is given `update quantity`
**3.** If just coupon is given `apply coupon`
**4.** If nothing is given `do nothing`

```
// quantity
$qty = $request->input('quantity');
$products = Product::findOrFail($request->proId);
$stock = $products->stock;

// coupons
$couponcode = $request->input('coupon');
$catId = Coupon::where('category_id', $products->category_id)
               ->where('value_to', '>=', $mytime)
               ->when($couponcode, function ($query) use ($couponcode) {
                    return $query->where('title', $couponcode);
                })
               ->first();

if (!empty($qty) && !empty($couponcode)) { // 1. if both (quantity and couponcode) are given
    if ($qty < $stock && (!is_null($catId) && $catId->title == $couponcode)) { // if quantity < stock AND coupon-code is correct

        $coupon = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
            'name' => $catId->title,
            'type' => 'coupon',
            'target' => 'item',
            'value' => $catId->amount,
        ));

        Cart::update($id, array(
            'quantity' => array(
                'relative' => false,
                'value' => $qty,
            ),
            'conditions' => $coupon,
        ));

        Session::flash('success', 'Cart updated.');
        return redirect()->route('cart.index');

    } elseif ($qty > $stock) {
        Session::flash('danger', 'quantity not available!');
        return redirect()->route('cart.index');
    } else {
        Session::flash('danger', 'invalid coupon code!');
        return redirect()->route('cart.index');
    }
} elseif (!empty($qty)) { // 2. if just quantity is given   
    if ($qty < $stock) {

        Cart::update($id, array(
            'quantity' => array(
                'relative' => false,
                'value' => $qty,
            ),
        ));

        Session::flash('success', 'Cart updated.');
        return redirect()->route('cart.index');

    } else {
        Session::flash('danger', 'quantity not available!');
        return redirect()->route('cart.index');
    }
} elseif (!empty($couponcode)) { // 3. if just couponcode is given
    if (!is_null($catId) && $catId->title == $couponcode) {

        $coupon = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
            'name' => $catId->title,
            'type' => 'coupon',
            'target' => 'item',
            'value' => $catId->amount,
        ));

        Cart::update($id, array(
            'conditions' => $coupon,
        ));

        Session::flash('success', 'Coupon applied successfully.');
        return redirect()->route('cart.index');

    } else {
        Session::flash('danger', 'invalid coupon code!');
        return redirect()->route('cart.index');
    }
} else{ // 1. if nothing is given
    Session::flash('danger', 'Your request cannot be handle, please try again!');
    return redirect()->route('cart.index');
}
```

Comment: when I use coupon field as empty it will show session error. when i add wrong code it says `Trying to get property of non-object` it suppose to say nothing on empty input and show session alert on wrong input.

Comment: Check if the catId you are getting is not empty
`(! empty($catId) && $catId->title == $couponcode)` OR `(! is_null($catId) && $catId->title == $couponcode)` in first & third if's

Comment: I appreciate your work bro, I really do. here is 1mb video of results of your edited code http://sendvid.com/dgpovoc8 .

Comment: as you can see 1- quantity will not update however i get success message, 2- `qty` and `coupon` both together will not work, 3- coupon works once (which is good) but not sure about it yet. 4- my coupon amount is 10000 but it reduced 15000.

Comment: I think we have issue in this line `elseif (!empty($qty))` because no matter user change quantity or not there always will be quantity in that input.

Comment: According to your video, you have applied the same coupon code twice. First time, it worked and second time, didn't. But about quantity, you are right its not being updated...

Comment: One thing, I have missed is the minus sign (-) in ` -$catId->amount` ... This could be the reason for wrong coupon value...